# Vote to close as exact duplicate requires manual typing

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I paste a link into the vote to close as an exact duplicate, I have to hit something on my keyboard before it will register what I have pasted in. This only happens when you use the mouse to right click and paste.

This dialog window just sits here:

[image]

Back in '09 this was reported on [meta.StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26849/159711), but Jeff said it works fine and Random said that you just have to double click.

So either this is a bug, or I would like it to be a feature request that I don't have to double click.

Comment: I've never encountered this.  Can you more thoroughly describe the steps to reproduce it?  I've dropped a junk question [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/929/dummy-question-for-vote-to-close-bug-reproduction), feel free to use it for experimentation.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I don't have any great screen capture program that I can use right now, if needed I can do it tonight. It might be a browser specific issue, I am using chrome. If I right click and select paste, the link gets pasted, but the form doesn't acknowledge that I have done anything. This means that the "vote to close" button is left inactive. If I delete a character and retype it then it pulls up the question. If I use ctrl+v then it works just fine.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I did add a screen shot of what it sits on after pasting.

Comment: Oh, right-click to paste?  I never did that...I think I forgot it was possible.  Anyways, status-repro from Mac OS X 10.6 with Chrome.

Comment: Why would anyone use the mouse to paste when Ctrl-V does it? This makes no sense.  Considering all the rather more serious bugs in this forum, this is minor nit that I don't even see why anyone would run into.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I don't question the severity (or lack of) of this bug, but it is still a bug either way. I run into it when I am eating and surfing the web. I push my keyboard back and just use the mouse. Having to reach up to the keyboard is very annoying in this circumstance. I can also see people (probably on other non-technical site) not knowing about the keyboard shortcut and I see no reason we should leave a known bug that people will run into.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Disabled users, anyone?

Comment: @Kellenjb: I have no objection to any bug getting fixed, but it's funny how this very minor problem get so much attention when there are more serious long-standing bugs and annoyances nobody seems interested in.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, "interest" from kevin or myself is really no interest. This bug will not move anywhere until the dev team sees it. If we have a bug on meta that is really serious we can go try to raise alarms and start throwing fits to community coordinators but that is something that users can do also, we just do it in our secret hangout with the one handshake that kevin never gets right.

Answer (score 2):

I did reproduce this behavior successfully with right-click and paste.  I also reproduced it with the "paste" option in the Edit menu; that produces even more coolness by failing to trigger both the keyboard and mouse handlers, which are required to clear the "type or paste a question link or numeric question id" text, producing the following result:

[image]

It seems that these paste methods are not properly supported, you're right.

That said, it seems that neither the Stack Exchange developers, the testers, nor other users have had a significant problem with this limitation in the past three years.  We could try to detect this mose activity, but may I suggest keeping one hand on the keyboard?  Using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> (or <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> etc, if you're on a Mac) is much more efficient.

Consider it a productivity training tool courtesy of Stack Exchange, Inc.  It will make you more effective in many computer situations!  And all this for the low, low price of $19.95 (in 3 easy payments)!  <sup><sub>(contact me for information on where to send the money)</sub></sup> :)

Comment: Pretty much a copy and paste of what I told Olin...  I don't question the severity (or lack of) of this bug, but it is still a bug either way. I run into it when I am eating and surfing the web. I push my keyboard back and just use the mouse. Having to reach up to the keyboard is very annoying in this circumstance. I can also see people (probably on other non-technical site) not knowing about the keyboard shortcut and I see no reason we should leave a known bug that people will run into.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next build.